# VS2008 debugger breaks at unwanted line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, exception, breakpoints

Visual Studio 2008 breaks at the following line with the following message:
[image: VisualStudio8Debugger]

I don't want it to stop there, it's making debugging a nightmare. Somehow the exception thrown at line 998 is causing this, even though there is a try...catch block somewhere up there that is supposed to catch this exception. Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using the debug build to debug your application. And did you check if you have set the /O flag, if yes then remove it. It did cause me a lot of heartburn while debugging, similarly like yours.

Comment: I was debugging in Release mode just now. Why would it behave differently if there's a custom catch block set up for this?

Comment: Primarily because of missing symbolic debugging information. Here is the MSDN link for debugging a release build. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems convinced there's not actually an active try block on the stack.  But double-check that the Debug + Exceptions, Thrown check boxes are off.  Also make sure you've got the Debug configuration selected and verify Tools + Options, Debugging, General, "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is ticked.